# Run a bash script via cron and save variable to be used in the cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, redhat

I have the following cronjob running on RHEL 7.5:

`5 12 * * *  root /mydir/myscript.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s "My Script: myscript.sh has run" root@mycompany.com`

The script `myscript.sh` basically will output a result at the end of it - 0 for Success and 1 for failures. This is stored in the variable `$result`.

My question: is it possible to have $result be read in the cronjob so I can change it to something like:

`5 12 * * *  root /mydir/myscript.sh 2>&1 | mailx -s "My Script: myscript.sh has run with error code $result" root@mycompany.com`

This way I can tell from the subject whether the script has run successfully or not.
So far I havent found a way to save `$result` into a variable that keeps its value that can be read by cron. Is this possible (I'm sure some of your geniuses out there will have a solution!)

UPDATE:
I know that I can send an email from the script itself but there is a requirement that prevents me from doing this so it has to be done from the cronjob itself.

Thanks J

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this

```
5 12 * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'result=`/mydir/myscript.sh` | mailx -s "My Script: myscript.sh has run with error code $result" root@mycompany.com'
```

Another way is just to update `myscript` to send the email

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply. I ran the cronjob as you suggested and it ran but `$result` is empty in the subject. And the body is now gone (I get `Null message body; hope that's ok` message the job runs). How can I get `$result` in the subject and still have the body intact in the email? Thanks

Comment: can you share the content of `myscript.sh`

Comment: try to use it this way : 5 12 * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'result=$(/mydir/myscript.sh) | mailx -s "My Script: myscript.sh has run with error code $result" root@mycompany.com'